# Invoking a method I created to decrease the value of a variable does not have an effect to the value. How can I solve this?

Tags: java

My assignment is to create a program that simulates the usage of a prepaid mobile phone. It can only have four attributes namely double creditsLeft, int totalMinutesCalled, double ratePerCall and int textMessagesSent.

The class should implement these methods:void load( double pesos ),void call( int minutes ),double getLoadLeft(),int getTotalMinutesCalled(),void printSummary().

When the printSummary method is called, a report about the attributes of the MobilePhone instance should be printed out following this.

```
package javaPackage;
public class Driver{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MobilePhone mp = new MobilePhone();
        mp.load(34.50);
        mp.call(1);
        mp.printSummary();
        mp.sendTextMessages();
        System.out.println(mp.getNumTextMessages());
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Credits left: P27.00  
Total call duration: 1 mins.  
Rate per call: P6.50  
Number of text messages sent: 1
```

Here's my code.

```
package javaPackage;
public class MobilePhone {
         double creditsLeft;
         int totalMinutesCalled;
         double ratePerCall;
         int textMessagesSent;

    public MobilePhone(){
        creditsLeft=0;
        totalMinutesCalled=0;
        ratePerCall=6.50;
        textMessagesSent=0;
    }   
    public void call(int minutes){
        totalMinutesCalled=minutes; 
    }
    public  void load( double pesos ){
        creditsLeft=pesos;
    }   
    public int getTotalMinutesCalled(){
        return totalMinutesCalled;
    }   
    public void changeRate(double newCallRate){
        ratePerCall=newCallRate;
    }
    public void sendTextMessages(){ 
        creditsLeft--;
    }
    public int getNumTextMessages(){    
        return textMessagesSent ;
    }   
    public void printSummary(){
        System.out.println("Credits left:"+ (creditsLeft -(totalMinutesCalled*ratePerCall)));
        System.out.println("Total call duration:" +totalMinutesCalled);
        System.out.println("Rate per call:"+ ratePerCall);
        System.out.print("Numer of text messages sent:" );
    }   
}
```

However, I have some problems. Invoking sendTextMessages() does not decrease the value of creditsLeft.

Also, how can I show how many times sendTextMessages() is invoked to show how many times a text message is sent? I'm not allowed to use any more variables other than the ones I mentioned above.

Here's my output.

```
Credits left:28.0
Total call duration:1
Rate per call:6.5
Number of text messages sent:0
```

Right now, the number of text messages sent is always 0 because I don't know how to complete this program yet. And the credits left should be 27 since I invoked sendTextMessages() once.

I'm very new to programming and know only few things. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is creditsLeft declared?

Comment: Is it in the phone class?

Comment: Yes. It's under mobilePhone

Comment: You do realize that you're calling `mp.printSummary()` *before* calling `mp.sendTextMessages()`? So the latter can't possibly have any impact on the values printed by the former.

Comment: See my answer for reason.

Comment: Also you are not increasing textMessagesSent, add this to the sendTextMessage function .e.g textMessagesSent++;

Comment: Props to you for noticing that, flew right passed me :) 

Gave you an upvote. :)

Comment: "I'm not allowed to use any more variables other than the ones I mentioned above." This probably only holds for the end result. For debugging, you should be able to add variables and remove them later again.

Comment: In that case, you would have to calculate the difference between how many credits they started with to how many they have when report is generated.

Answer (score 2):

It changes! You don't see it because you have to call

```
phone.printSummary()
```

a second time after you sent the text messages.

Regarding your second question:
You already declared the field 'textMessagesSent'. Use it by incrementing it every time sendTextMessages() is called. The final method would look like this:

```
public void sendTextMessages(){
   creditsLeft--;
   textMessagesSent++;
}
```

Also consider to update the 'creditsLeft' field when the call()-method is invoked.

Comment: Oh my. I overlooked that. Thanks. can you also answer my other question about counting how many times a text message is sent?

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

If I am right you are calling printSummary before inflicting the change, so it is returning values before sending. Try calling it after calling the Send Message functions.

Solution:

```
package javaPackage;
public class Driver{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MobilePhone mp = new MobilePhone();
        mp.load(34.50);
        mp.call(1);            
        mp.sendTextMessages();
        mp.printSummary();
        System.out.println(mp.getNumTextMessages());
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed top call if you need it, just leave it there. But make sure bottom call stays or will not work :)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I completely overlooked that one. May you also help me with my other question about counting how many times sendTextMessages() is invoked?

Comment: Kindly click the tick next to my answer to mark it correct also.

Answer (score 1):

For your second answer, simply create a variable something like 'MessagesSent' will be fine, and increment it when the Send Message function is called. This variable needs to be global not local; in other words stick it in the class but not in a function.

```
    int messagesSent = 0;

    private void sentTextMessages(){
        creditsLeft --;
        messagesSent ++;
    }
```